# Ngrx dispatch action not working if request is still pending

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a component that gets object details by subscription (no ngrx or api involved at this time).

After getting the information i'm dispatching an action and retrieve the data.

Works good expect when there are many calls and if a request is still pending then no dispatching action is happened.

Is there any way to cancel the request and to refer to the last call?

any other approach or solution?

```
this.service.currentMessage.subscribe((selected) => {
      if(selected) {
        this.obj = {
          id: selected.id
        };
        // when there are many calls and a call is still in pending then
        // this row actually not happened and no call made
        this.store.dispatch(new FetchList(this.obj));
      }
    });
```

thanks

Comment: why do you trigger a dispatch action in a subscribe block ? You should run it in a your effect or in a guard or in a ngOnInit block.

Comment: I'm quite new to this - this code is part of the ngOnInit block

Comment: In your State you should have a loaded prop so you can check for it

Comment: You should dispatch action in your init check for the loaded prop in your effect ofType(yourAction) run the service

Comment: Try to describe your flow so people can help you. What's trigger currentMessage ?

Comment: currentMessage is triggered by clicking an item from a list.It just a way of transferring data between sibling components.

Comment: at (click) trigger a action that trigger currentMessage that trigger FetchList :) you manage all this in your effects

Comment: this question is hard to answer with only this code block. Some more details or a reproduction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of ways to solve this problem is to stop multiple request. So in your service where you get Data add RxJs ShareReplay operator like this:

```
this.http.get('your url')
.pipe(
shareReplay);
```

This means when you request many times , if request is already pending other requests will be ignored.

Comment: Any method to cancel the pending requests and to execute the last request?

Comment: yes use switchMap operator. This will simply cancel previous request and execute latest. this.http.get('your url')
.pipe(switchMap);

Comment: You are welcome ! Please do not forget to mark question as answer :)

Comment: What is exactly the syntax and parameters of the switchMap?

Comment: in switch you include observable that you want cancel and renew. in this situation switchMap(this.http.get('your url')).